# Rails Complex Model Association, Shared Document Between Users and Teams

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rails-activerecord, model-associations, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a complex model association in mind, and was wondering how I could accomplish it. This is what i want to accomplish.

- I have a User and a Document model
- A User can create documents. He is now the document admin.

  1. He can add other users to his document, and give them permissions such as Editor, Viewer, Admin
  2. He can also make a team, a group of users, and add multiple teams to his document. Each user on a team that the User has added to his document will also have permissions. A user can belong to many teams.

I am a little bit confused about the associations I will have to setup. This is the code I have so far, which has not incorporated the team aspect:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :participations
  has_many :documents, through: :participations
end

class Document < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :participations
  has_many :users, through: :participations
end

class Participation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :document
  enum role: [ :admin, :editor, :viewer ]
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend introducing a Team and TeamMembership models in a similary way to existing models. Also change the belongs_to association on Participation from `user` to a polymorphic `participant`.

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :team_memberships
  has_many :users, through: :team_memberships
  has_many :participations, as: :participant
end

class TeamMembership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :team_memberships
  has_many :teams, through: :team_memberships
  has_many :participations, as: :participant
end

class Participation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :participant, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :document
  enum role: [ :admin, :editor, :viewer ]
end

class Document < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :participations

  # if desired create a users method to conveniently get a list of users with access to the document
  def users
    @users ||= participations.flat_map do |participation|
      case participation.partipant
      when User
        [participation.participant]
      when Team
        participation.participant.users
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I would only add has_many :through associations as you discover a benefit/need to having them. That will reduce complexity of maintaining them unless you have specific use case for them. In the case of User having a teams association, it's pretty obvious that you'll be likely to want to get the teams that the user is a part of and since there's no specific information in the TeamMembership object that you are likely to need in that determination, it's a good has_many :through to have.

EDIT: Added `Document` model.

Comment: Is using a polymorphic association "better" than a `has_many through:` association? Because in my answer, I am still using the same amount of models, so is it really reducing complexity?

Comment: @Coenwulf What would the `document` model look like in this setup?

Comment: @Redline No, polymorphic associations aren't better then has_many through associations. They solve different problems. I also wasn't really trying to say that has_many through associations are bad in any way. As with any technology, they fill a certain role, and I was urging not making them until they are useful. Once the benefit is clearly seen, certainly make them!

Comment: @yibix There isn't a significant change to the Document model in what I was presenting. That's why I didn't document it. I'll add it in my answer to clarify. The only real change is that the users association is probably not a good idea. A users method would probably fit better.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have a `participation` model, you can use that as the join model between users and teams. Since a `user` can belong to multiple teams, and a document can have multiple teams, you can use a has_many through relationship between teams and documents. We'll call it the `DocumentTeam` model.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :participations
  has_many :documents, through: :participations
  has_many :teams, through: :participations
end

class Participation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :document
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :team, optional: true
  enum role: [ :admin, :editor, :viewer ]
end

class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :participations
  has_many :users, through: :participations
  has_many :document_teams
  has_many :document, through: :document_teams
end

class Document < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :participations
  has_many :users, through: :participations
  has_many :document_teams
  has_many :teams, through: :document_teams
end

class DocumentTeam < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :document
  belongs_to :team
end
```